# How to attribute value to dataframe rows based on another df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with football games like this, let's call it games_df:

| Date | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | GoalsH | GoalsA | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18/02/2024 | Sheffield United | Brighton | 0 | 5 | A |
| 18/02/2024 | Luton | Man United | 1 | 2 | A |
| 19/02/2024 | Everton | Crystal Palace | 1 | 1 | D |
| 20/02/2024 | Man City | Brentford | 1 | 0 | H |
| 21/02/2024 | Liverpool | Luton | 4 | 1 | H |

And I have a one dataframe per team, for example team_df that has historical league position like this:

| Position | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-14 | 2021-08-20 |
| 3 | 2021-08-21 | 2021-08-27 |
| 6 | 2021-08-28 | 2021-09-11 |

How can I retrieve the position from each team_df given the Date at game_df, so that I can update it like this:

| Date | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | GoalsH | GoalsA | Result | HomePos | AwayPos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18/02/2024 | Sheffield United | Brighton | 0 | 5 | A | 20 | 7 |
| 18/02/2024 | Luton | Man United | 1 | 2 | A | 17 | 6 |
| 19/02/2024 | Everton | Crystal Palace | 1 | 1 | D | 18 | 15 |
| 20/02/2024 | Man City | Brentford | 1 | 0 | H | 2 | 14 |
| 21/02/2024 | Liverpool | Luton | 4 | 1 | H | 1 | 18 |

I can do it by going through each row of games and getting the value from the corresponding team_df with:

```
position=team_df.loc[(team_df["From"]>=game_df.loc[i,"Date"]) & (team_df["To"]<=game_df.loc[i,"Date"]), "Position"]
```

But I want a more efficient way to do it

Comment: use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)